# How do you access data in a Ruby on Rails controller that is POSTed via an AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm sending an AJAX request and posting some json data to the server. How do I access this data in my controller (I'm using Ruby on Rails).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be trivial:

```
data = ActiveSupport::JSON::decode(params[:param_with_json_string])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Content-Type of the post request to `application/json` then Rails will handle things for you and make the data available in the params hash like normal.

Example using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/some_url', 
  data: {user: {name:"Bob", email: "bob@example.com"}}, 
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'POST'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Access the parameter through the params hash. There should be no need to decode JSON. Rails should convert it into a hash for you.